# ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined word press add post

Tags: wordpress, console.log, wordpress-admin

I am using wordpress latest and while add post it's showing me error at Add Post as ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined in console browser please help.

It's wordpress back end add post nothing to customized

Comment: are you using any plugin for anything ?

Comment: Using plugins as Really Simple SSL,classic editer and XML Sitemap & Google News 

Also Tested deactivating all plugins

Comment: which plugin is creating console error ?

Comment: no this is not related to plugin error, As I checked error path in console it's showing js from wp-includes and which are already build by WP, also updated WP version still not resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` to your `wp-config.php` file just below the `define('DB_HOST' line.`

Comment: Why? can you please explain it.